# What is the best way to sort a data bound combo box?

Tags: c#, data-binding

I have done a bit of research into this and it seems that the only way to sort a data bound combo box is to sort the data source itself (a DataTable in a DataSet in this case).

If that is the case then the question becomes what is the best way to sort a DataTable?

The combo box bindings are set in the designer initialize using

```
myCombo.DataSource = this.typedDataSet;
myCombo.DataMember = "Table1";
myCombo.DisplayMember = "ColumnB";
myCombo.ValueMember = "ColumnA";
```

I have tried setting

```
this.typedDataSet.Table1.DefaultView.Sort = "ColumnB DESC";
```

But that makes no difference, I have tried setting this in the control constructor, before and after a typedDataSet.Merge call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using a DataTable, you can use the (DataTable.DefaultView) [DataView.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.sort.aspx) property. For greater flexibility you can use the [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.aspx) component. BindingSource will be the DataSource of your combobox. Then you can change your data source from a DataTable to List without changing the DataSource of the combobox.

> The BindingSource component serves
>   many purposes. First, it simplifies
>   binding controls on a form to data by
>   providing currency management, change
>   notification, and other services
>   between Windows Forms controls and
>   data sources.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually sort the [default view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.defaultview.aspx) on a DataTable:

```
myDataTable.DefaultView.Sort = "Field1, Field2 DESC";
```

That'll sort any rows you retrieve directly from the DataTable.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you bind the DefaultView to the Controls Datasource, after you set the Sort property, and not the table:

```
myCombo.DataSource = this.typedDataSet.Tables["Table1"].DefaultView;
myCombo.DisplayMember = "ColumnB";
myCombo.ValueMember = "ColumnA";
```

Answer (score 1):

Josh Smith has a [blog post](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/06/20/displaying-sorted-enum-values-in-a-combobox/) that answers this question, and does it all in XAML.

Answer (score 0):

Does the data need to be in a DataTable?
Using a SortedList and binding that to a combo box would be a simpler way.

If you need to use a DataTable you can use the Select method to retrieve a DataView and pass in a sort parameter.

```
DataView dv = myDataTable.Select("filter expression", "sort");
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to sort a ComboBox is to use the [ComboBox.Sorted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.sorted.aspx) property. However, that won't work if you're using data binding. In that case you'll have to sort the data source itself.

You can use either a [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319(VS.80).aspx) or [SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) (both sort by the Key), or a [DataView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.aspx).

The DataView has a [Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.sort.aspx) property that accepts a sort expression (string) for example:

```
view.Sort = "State, ZipCode DESC";
```

In the above example both State and ZipCode are columns in the DataTable used to create the DataView.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that you've already chosen your answer to this question, but I would have suggested placing a DataView on your form, binding it to your DataSet/DataTable, and setting the sort on the View in the designer. You then bind your combobox to the DataView, rather than the DataSet/DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: make a stored procedure in SQL server that returns the ordered list and bind a datasource to it.