# how to sort data in my combobox

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have data in my combobox1 and was wondering if it would be possible to sort the data  in the combobox alphabetically?

I have spent ages trying to find the answer by searching the forum but couldnt find anything, I would really appreciate your help..

```
With ComboBox2
  .DisplayMember = "Name"
  .ValueMember = "FullName"
  .DataSource = New IO.DirectoryInfo("Path").GetFiles() _
  .Select(Function(fi) New With {.Name = _
          IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.FullName), fi.FullName}) _
  .ToArray()
End With
```

Comment: What is your datasource?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29731/what-is-the-best-way-to-sort-a-data-bound-combo-box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort your data first, then bind it to your combobox.

```
With ComboBox1
  .DisplayMember = "Name"
  .ValueMember = "FullName"
  .DataSource = New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\asdf").GetFiles() _
  .Select(Function(fi) New With {.Name = _
          IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.FullName), fi.FullName}) _
  .OrderBy(Function(fi) CType(fi.Name, Integer)) _
  .ToArray()
End With
```

Comment: My code to load the combo box is as follows  `co     With ComboBox2
            .DisplayMember = "Name"
            .ValueMember = "FullName"
            .DataSource = New IO.DirectoryInfo("Path").GetFiles().
                                               Select(Function(fi) New With {.Name = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.FullName), fi.FullName}).
                                               ToArray()


        End With   de`

Comment: I have just edited the question, sorry but im new to this site so not sure how to add tags around my code.

Comment: @user1413746 I added an order by to the linq query. Try that.

Comment: Nope still not sorted, where the fields should be sorted like 1, 2, 3, 40, 50, 60, 112, 200, 300 they are displaying like 1, 2, 200, 3, 300, 40, 50, 60

Comment: @user1413746 AHAHA! They are being sorted as strings, I updated the code to convert them to integers before sorting, try that.

Comment: this is really strange because when I try the coding now my combobox is empty?

Comment: I ran it on my computer and it worked. How is the code above being called? Form_Load?

Comment: No, I have it in a sub and call it.

Comment: Sorry i'm such a noob i still had your coding as combobox1 :/ many thanks for all your help, its working now.

Answer (score 3):

set the `.Sorted` property to `TRUE`

Comment: I tried that but it wont work as my combobox is bound, so it displays the data like:

Comment: sort your datasource first.  ie. sort the query.

Comment: [According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.sorted.aspx) that property will not work when using a databound values.

Comment: The original question did not indicate that the control was bound.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just add a .orderby LINQ predicate where you set the data source?

```
.DataSource = unsorted.Select( ... ).OrderBy(Function(x) x.name).ToArray()
```

Answer (score -1):

select the property "data source" for the combobox and click at the triple dots, a query will be shown, then sort the field in Ascending order save all and restart the database,
good luck,,

Waleed

Comment: -1. A query shown at design-time for `IO.DirectoryInfo("Path").GetFiles` set at runtime? Are you sure?